# Event handler with parameters in dynamically created elements

Tags: javascript

When I assign the event handler without parameters, it works: http://jsfiddle.net/mUj43/

```
function show(){
    alert('work');
}

var myButton = document.createElement("input");  
myButton.type="button";  
myButton.value="click";   
myButton.onclick=show;

var where = document.getElementById("where");
where.appendChild(myButton);  ​
```

but if I pass parameters, it doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/mUj43/1/

```
myButton.onclick = show('test');
```

How can I use function with parameters in dynamically created elements?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't do that, you could use partial application by creating a new function and then attach that as event handler:

```
myButton.onclick=show.bind( myButton, 'test');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mUj43/2/

Docs (which I recommend you read because this function is useful for many other things as well) and compatibility information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: +1 for an accurate answer, though you should point out that it doesn't work in IE8, even though that info is available on MDN.

Comment: @JosephSilber With the provided code in the link, it does. I did note that the link contains compatibility information, it even contains code that works in IE.

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to create your own closure:

```
myButton.onclick = function () {
    show.call(this, 'test');
};
```

You could also use @Esailija's `bind` method, but this one has deeper browser support.

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
myButton.onclick = function(){show("test");}
```

or :

```
myButton.onclick = function(){ show.call( this, "test");}
```

if you want to retain the element object context inside the show function

Comment: You could use `show.call( this, "test");` to retain the element object context inside the show function

Answer (score 0):

That's because when you add events you need a function reference.

In your first example, `show` is a reference to a function.

In your second example, `show('test')` is a call to the function `show`, which returns nothing, and nothing isn't a function reference.

That's why when you load the page, it alerts "work" (the function is called), but when you click the button no function is called.

Then, you need a function.

You can declare it:

```
myButton.onclick=f;
function f(){
   show('test')
}
```

Or you can use an anonymous one:

```
myButton.onclick=function(){
   show('test')
}
```